# How can you implement SafeArea for flame?

Tags: flutter, flame

Heyo,
i have been trying to look for a possibility to implement SafeArea (or something equal to that) in my flame game. I found this (https://github.com/ikbendewilliam/flutter_flame_architecture/blob/main/lib/src/widgets/flame_safe_area.dart) but I dont know how to fully implement this in the screen leading to the game [image]

Is there a simple solution for this issue I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `GameWidget` that you wrap your `FlameGame` in is just a normal Flutter widget you can put the `GameWidget` as a child of a `SafeArea`.